# LinkButton in a repeater 'onclick' assigns a value to a hidden input

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have a `asp:LinkButton` that's inside a repeater , that has a `commandname` containing an `ID`

```
 <table>                    
        <asp:Repeater ID = "rptr" runat = "server">
         <ItemTemplate>
             <tr>

                <td>
                     <asp:LinkButton ID = "lbtn" runat = "server" 
                        text = '<%#showData(Container.DataItem, "CommonName")%>' 
                        CommandName = '<%#showData(Container.DataItem, "ID")%>' 
                        CommandArgument = '<%#showData(Container.DataItem, "CommonName")%>'  />

                </td>
                    </tr>
         </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:Repeater>
    </table>
```

Also, I have a hidden `input` field: (outside of the repeater)

```
<input type = "hidden" id = "ID" runat = "server" />
```

The repeater populates many `asp:LinkButton`, and each one has a unique `ID` that's stored in the `commandname`. when a `asp:LinkButton` is clicked, I want the hidden input value to store the `commandname` of the button that's been clicked.

I know that I have to use some sort of javascript function in the `onclick` event. But I am not able to figure out the specific way to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where you place your input field ? is it inside repeater or outside ?

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar outside.

Comment: Do you need the postback of the LinkButton or will a clientside solution be sufficient?

Comment: @VDWWD postback for the LinkButton is not needed in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this inside the repeater:

```
<a href="javascript:fillHiddenField(<%# Container.ItemIndex %>, '<%# Eval("ID").ToString() %>')">Fill field</a>
```

And then a `HiddenField` and a javascript function outside the repeater to store the value.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function fillHiddenField(rowNumber, rowValue) {
        document.getElementById("<%= HiddenField1.ClientID %>").value = rowValue;
    }
```

Now you won't have to do a postback to get the value in the hidden field but it is still available on postback done by another element.

P.S. it's better not to use "ID" as the ID of elements, it could cause confusion. As are the spaces before and after the = signs.